# What would be the residue of $\frac{f^\prime(z)}{f(z)}$

Tags: complex-analysis

Let us consider $z_0$ is a zero of the analytic function f(z) which is non-constant.

What could we say about the reside of $\frac{f^\prime(z)}{f(z)}$ at $z_0$

Comment: Hint: Re-read and edit your question. And write $f(z)$ as a factor of $z_{0}$ (if it is what you want to call your zero) with the appropriate multipliticy times an analytic function. Then use logartihmic derivative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose that $f$ is analytic in an open set $D$, $z_0 \in D$ and that $f$ has in $z_0$ a zero of order $k \in \mathbb N$. Then $f'$ has in $z_0$ a zero of order $k-1$. Thus there are analytic function $g,h$  such that

$f'(z)=(z-z_0)^{k-1}g(z)$ and $f(z)=(z-z_0)^kh(z)$ for $z \in D$

and

$g(z_0)=\frac{f^{(k-1)}(z_0)}{(k-1)!} \ne 0$ and $h(z_0)=\frac{f^{(k)}(z_0)}{k!} \ne 0$.

Now let $\phi:=g/h$. Let $C$ be a small circle cebtered at $z_0$. Then we have (with Cauchy)

$res(f'/f;z_0)=\frac{1}{2 \pi i}\int_C \frac{\phi(z)}{z-z_0}=\phi(z_0)=\frac{g(z_0)}{h(z_0)}=k \frac{f^{(k-1)}(z_0)}{f^{(k)}(z_0)}$

Edit: above, $g(z_0)$ is not correct. Correct is $g(z_0)=\frac{f^{(k)}(z_0)}{(k-1)!}$

Thus $res(f'/f;z_0)=k$

Comment: That's not correct. Look at your $g(z_0)$ again, you made a mistake there.

Comment: Thank you ! I will edit my answer

Comment: I think it's better to replace the wrong version with the right one rather than appending. Perhaps it's instructive if you write $g(z_0) = \frac{1}{(k-1)!} \bigl(f'\bigr)^{(k-1)}(z_0) = \frac{1}{(k-1)!} f^{(k)}(z_0)$?